# Show pages elements default jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a registration page  with 2 radiobuttons (2 types of registration) in the top.

When the first radiobutton is checked, I see forms for first type of registration. 
When second radiobutton checked, I see forms for second type.

I realize it by adding jquery code to radiobutton input:

```
onclick="jQuery('.school_field').hide();jQuery('.priv_field').show();
```

Problem: When I go to the registration page I see all forms that I created (for 2 types of registration). How can I display by default forms for 1-st type of registration?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hide the forms by default on page load and show only one.

May be this helps

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.school_field').hide();
    jQuery('.priv_field').show();    

})
```

Comment: Thank U! It works! This is my first jquery steps . I am happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS to have all `priv_field` elements hidden during page load:

```
.priv_field { display: none; }
```

The same could be achieved with jQuery, although I don't see a case for it:

```
$(function() { $('.priv_field').hide(); });
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the jQuery-solution also might reveal the hidden fields for some time, until the DOM is ready. If the CSS loads slowly, that might ofcourse be the case for that solution as well, but  the jQuery-solution will likely be even slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use show() and hide() .
Thats kind of simple

have a look http://jsfiddle.net/nagoba/ZvQw6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#form1").click(function(){

        $('#form2').attr('checked',false);
        $("#f1").show();
        $("#f2").hide();

    });

    $("#form2").click(function(){

        $('#form1').attr('checked',false); 
         $("#f2").show();
        $("#f1").hide();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean hiding/showing of *fields*, not *forms*, that are only for the first/second registration type?

When DOM is ready, you should check which radio button is selected initially and then hide/show the fields based on this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('input.radio-button-for-school').is(':selected')) {
    $('.priv_field').hide();
    $('.school_field').show();
  } else {
    $('.school_field').hide();
    $('.priv_field').show();
  }
});
```

Note that in certain browsers, if you set form fields to certain values and then reload the page, the form fields will still hold the same value. So it is not enough IMO to just assume that your default radio button will always be the one that's selected when you load the page. You might also want to retain the users' input if they submit the form but it has some invalid values.